# Is possible for a vps service with own ip addresses to have ports restricted?

Tags: vps, service, host, limitations

I am looking for a cheap vps service, and i found some, but the most appellative i found for what i need ("fileMedia") has a really bad translation on its page and there is something which is leaving me some doubt.

This service, just like many others i found is for a kvm slot for free use (no hard restrictions on usage/OS/etc...) but when i try to order there are some fields for ntp and ftp storage for an additional cost, and i don't understand why since the plan itself has own storage, the user supposedly only needs to install a server like vsftpd or pureftp.

Since i had this question i asked my programming teacher for a reason for it, and he just told me that he doesn't has a vps of his own, but that there is a possibility that the firewall outside the server limits the ports, and those "additional features" are needed to unlock them.

How can i tell if its true, if i don't have time to wait for the technical support answer (probably tomorrow or even monday)? Do vps providers actually do these things?

Comment: I'm not following, what does a firewall have to do with you on an order form?  Only the company offering the product/service can legitimately answer pre-sales questions.  The answer for your title is 'yes'.  Only the VPN provider can tell you for sure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is best answered by the service provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Is possible for a vps service with own ip addresses to have ports
>   restricted?

Yes, the upstream provider can apply whatever ACL/firewall restrictions they like within the network to restrict what can/can't reach your host -- this is basically a perimeter firewall even though you're different entities (the provider and you/customer) the network is still "just a network" so just like I can control the perimeter firewall on my business network to prevent traffic reaching internal hosts (or internal hosts reaching out), so can the provider apply restrictions to your traffic.

Having said that, as @etagenklo said, this most probably isn't what they are talking about in the sign-up page. They are probably offering backup space etc.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no restrictions on usage in the contract/terms of service, usually no ports or protocols should be blocked. I rather think that the offer for FTP storage means storage on an external FTP backup server where you can upload backups of the data on your VPS. This is quite a common offer.